# DVB-T tune request parameters

Tags: c++, directshow, video-capture

I'm working in GraphEdit to capture video from a Pinnacle PCTV card, in preparation for writing a program that will do the same, among other things.

What, precisely, is the meaning of the tune request parameters? How do I find the appropriate values to use, and is there a way to do so automatically? (ie, not to have to manually change params in the final program when trying to watch DVB in different countries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TransEdit](http://www.dvbviewer.com/griga/TransEdit%20E/MainWindow.html) can help you find some parameters. The ONID you can find on [dvbservices.com](http://www.dvbservices.com/identifiers/original_network_id?page=1). As far as I know you need to be able to configure the following values:

```
IDVBTLocator::put_CarrierFrequency()
IDVBTLocator::put_Bandwidth()
IDVBTuneRequest::put_SID()
IDVBTuneRequest::put_TSID()
IDVBTuneRequest::put_ONID()
```

For the Bandwidth I was even able to use -1. But I have only tested two different countries in europe.